# Perform calculation for every input in list in C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

My program have about 4 input that to each bearinglist and distanceList. How can i perform the calculation for all the input from both bearingList and distanceList then add to new list(latList) ? Below final result using the suggestion method, but the value all wrong the value in quote is the correct one that i calculate manually using calculator. It is cause by my loop?

```
Latitude :145.813468086875    (wrong)  
Latitude :-375.892492736719
Latitude :541.064120980176
Latitude :200.457427906608
Departure :244.990698852993
Departure :-480.992761280433
Departure :475.753137023761
Departure :32.0284185851739
```

> Latitude Departure (Correct)
>
> +255.88   +125.72
>
> -153.70   +590.78
>
> -694.28   -192.54
>
> +202.91   -6.02
>
> +388.48   -517.41

```
        List<double>bearingList = new List<double>();
        List<double> distanceList = new List<double>();

        Console.WriteLine("Insert bearing angle A:");
        double bearA = 26.16667;
        bearingList.Add(bearA);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert distance travel from A:");
        double distA = 285.10;
        distanceList.Add(distA);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert bearing angle B:");
        double bearB = 104.58;
        bearingList.Add(bearB);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert distance travel from B:");
        double distB = 610.45;
        distanceList.Add(distB);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert bearing angle C:");
        double bearC = 195.5;
        bearingList.Add(bearC);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert distance travel from C:");
        double distC = 720.48;
        distanceList.Add(distC);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert bearing angle D:");
        double bearD = 358.3;
        bearingList.Add(bearD);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert distance travel from D:");
        double distD = 203.0;
        distanceList.Add(distD);

        List<double> latList = new List<double>();


        for (int i = 0; i < distanceList.Count; i++)
        {
            var result1 = distanceList[i] * Math.Cos(bearingList[i]);
            latList.Add(result1);
            Console.WriteLine("Latitude :" + latList[i]);
        }

        //double calLat = distanceList. * Math.Cos(bearingList[0]);
        //latList.Add(calLat);
        List<double> departList = new List<double>();

        for (int i = 0; i < distanceList.Count; i++)
        {
            var result2 = distanceList[i] * Math.Sin(bearingList[i]);
            departList.Add(result2);
            Console.WriteLine("Departure :" + departList[i]);
        }
```

Comment: What about a `for` loop?

Comment: @John just update the code and i use loop for the list. My bad forgot to convert the bearing angle that in degree to rad. That why the value all wrong.

Answer (score 6):

You could make a list of named `Tuple` and use *Linq*

```
var list = new List<(double distance, double bearing)>();
list.Add((234,456));

var results = list.Select(x => x.distance * Math.Cos(x.bearing));
```

Or you could [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) them together with Linq

```
List<double>bearingList = new List<double>();
List<double> distanceList = new List<double>();

var results = distanceList.Zip(bearingList, (d, b) => d * Math.Cos(b));
```

Or a good old fashioned for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < distanceList.Count; i++)
{
   // do something
   var result = distance[i] * Math.Cos(bearing[i]);
   Results.Add(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I use the old fashioned loop for now, since i don't quite understand the Tuple and Linq method you mentioned, but i will use it as reference when i already understand it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "loop" to calculate all the elements of both lists and add them to the new List. If you haven't learned the concept of "loop", you can calculate them one by one.

Comment: Yeah,  i just use the loop you mentioned. Since i still new and dont quite understand the other method. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Trying to add more options , here is another solution using Enumerable.Range

```
List<double> bearingList = new List<double>();
List<double> distanceList = new List<double>();

var results = Enumerable.Range(0, bearingList.Count).Select(n => distanceList[n] + Math.Cos(bearingList[n])).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice, i will try it out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This my code after using the loop method for list. The Edited code above i forgot to convert the angle to rad for bearing.

```
        List<double>bearingList = new List<double>();
        List<double> distanceList = new List<double>();

        Console.WriteLine("Insert bearing angle A:");
        double bearA = 26.16667;
        bearingList.Add(bearA);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert distance travel from A:");
        double distA = 285.10;
        distanceList.Add(distA);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert bearing angle B:");
        double bearB = 104.58;
        bearingList.Add(bearB);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert distance travel from B:");
        double distB = 610.45;
        distanceList.Add(distB);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert bearing angle C:");
        double bearC = 195.5;
        bearingList.Add(bearC);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert distance travel from C:");
        double distC = 720.48;
        distanceList.Add(distC);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert bearing angle D:");
        double bearD = 358.3;
        bearingList.Add(bearD);

        Console.WriteLine("Insert distance travel from D:");
        double distD = 203.0;
        distanceList.Add(distD);

        List<double> latList = new List<double>();



        for (int i = 0; i < distanceList.Count; i++)
        {
            bearingList[i] *= Math.PI / 180;
            var result1 = distanceList[i] * Math.Cos(bearingList[i]);
            latList.Add(result1);
            Console.WriteLine("Latitude :" + result1);
        }

        //double calLat = distanceList. * Math.Cos(bearingList[0]);
        //latList.Add(calLat);
        List<double> departList = new List<double>();

        for (int i = 0; i < distanceList.Count; i++)
        {
            bearingList[i] *= Math.PI / 180;
            var result2 = distanceList[i] * Math.Sin(bearingList[i]);
            departList.Add(result2);
            Console.WriteLine("Departure :" + departList[i]);
        }
```